# Wait for a callback inside a callback

Tags: java, android, callback

I need to connect to a device that needs a PIN. Therefore I need to use this method(I can't change this):

```
device.setPINCallbackListener(new PINCallbackListener() {
                    @Override
                    public String onRequestPIN(MyDevice device) {
                        //have the user enter PIN 
                        return pin;
                    }
```

I need to prompt the PIN exactly there, because something appears on the device's screen, while it's waiting for the PIN.

I guess I could just put a while(pin == null) before the return, but that's not exactly an elegant solution...

Comment: And the question is? How to make it wait for user input?

Comment: why cant you just use a different interface for when the pin is entered and use that to return the pin such as like a super interface that gets called when all the prerequisites are filled

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I would normally use startActivityForResult and then continue in onActivityResult(or implement my own callback), but I don't think I can just continue in another method, as I need to return the PIN in onRequestPin.

Comment: @tyczj thanks for your answer, could you elaborate on how that would work? I'm trying to wrap my head around it.